# How to change Programatically Product visiblity in Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I want to change product visibility using coding in Magento custom module(in Controller). i am trying below code but visibility is not changed.

Please suggest right way.

```
$relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/category/indexer/product')->getCollection();


Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);   

     foreach ($relContact as $product) {
        try {
        $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);

        //$product->setVisiblity(VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Product #".$product->getId()." Visiblity could not be changed: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a little guess, but if you're code does not trigger an error, I think you forget to save the product.

```
try {
    $product->save();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$product_id = 'your_product_id';
Mage::app('default');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load($product_id);
$product->setVisibility(4);
$product->save();       
?>
```

here product get by product id and updating the product with visibility 4. if you want to add new product

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$product_id = 'your_product_id';
Mage::app('default');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setVisibility(4);
$product->save();   
?>
```

Comment: using this way product hide/unhide from front-end , but still in admin panel product visibility value does not changed ? there are any way to do that.

Comment: you are adding new product or updating the existing one?

Comment: updating existing product.